# needing to iterate through a folder and store documents into a variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing, batch-rename

I need to iterate through a folder and collect all the documents and store them into a variable. Im stuck on how exactly to do this process. (has to be done as a batch file)

Currently im here:

```
@echo off 
REM bat file to import documents into client
REM set file location
set loc=""
FOR %%i IN (*) DO ECHO %%i
```

for set loc do i use that as a variable for the folder path? and for the loop is (*) the variable (loc)?

Comment: How many files might be in the folder?  How do you want them added to the `loc` variable (e.g., loc="file1.ext","file2.ext","file3.ext")?

Comment: sorry to clarify, I would like to loop through a dir and collect all .TIFF documents that are within this directory and store them into a variable, that i can export the data.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, your request is not practical because a variable can hold at most 8191 characters. It would not take that many files to exceed the capacity of a variable.

But if you know the number of files is relatively small, and the file name lengths are not particularly large, then the following will work most of the time.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "loc=,"
for %%F in (*) do (set loc=!loc!"%%F",)
set "loc=!loc:~1,-1!"
echo !loc!
```

The above fails in the rare cases where a file name contains `!` because delayed expansion corrupts the value of `%%F` when it contains `!`.

The fix is to start out with delayed expansion off, and then toggle it on and off within the loop. An extra FOR /F loop is used to transport the value of `!loc!` accross the ENDLOCAL barrier.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "loc=,"
for %%F in (*) do (
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  for /f "delims=" %%L in ("!loc!") do (
    endlocal
    (set loc=%%L"%%F",)
  )
)
(set loc=%loc:~1,-1%)
echo %loc%
```

Comment: Ahhh sorry, sorry! It's my Android browser. It sometimes cut part of the window. So I haven't seen the second part.

Comment: Thanks guys for you're input, the folder should contain .TIFF documents. for this line of code:for %%F in (*) do (set loc=!loc!"%%F",) what does the (**) do?

Comment: @Manu - It instructs FOR to select all files. If you want just .TIFF, then change to `(*.tiff)`